# one-to-many relation error in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
 public function comments()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
  }
```

in the model userPost stores the posts;the foreign key is post_id and primary key is id.i am new in laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[link for laravel one to many relationship documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

```
hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Model would `Post` instead `userPost` it would work, because laravel treat foreign key as  `model name uderscore and id` means it search for `postUser_id` but you have `post_id`, so you need to explicitly pass as second parameter

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id', 'id'); 

//return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) says

> Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and
>   suffix it with _id